# Converting JSON to XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, json, xpath

I am new to json. I am having a program to generate xml from json object.

```
String str = "{'name':'JSON','integer':1,'double':2.0,'boolean':true,'nested':{'id':42},'array':[1,2,3]}";  
    JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( str );  
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();  
    xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility( false );  
    String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json );  
    System.out.println(xml);
```

the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<o><array json_class="array"><e json_type="number">1</e><e json_type="number">2</e><e json_type="number">3</e></array><boolean json_type="boolean">true</boolean><double json_type="number">2.0</double><integer json_type="number">1</integer><name json_type="string">JSON</name><nested json_class="object"><id json_type="number">42</id></nested></o>
```

my biggest problem is how to write my own attributes instead of json_type="number" and also writing my own sub elements like .

Comment: vinod,Have you got the solution for the above question, "Writing your own attributes to XML tags generated from json".? I'm also looking for the solution, if you found that, please post that in this thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Malleswari You may convert JSON to a map, modify it and then convert back.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use the (excellent) JSON-Java library from json.org then

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

`toString` can take a second argument to provide the name of the XML root node.

This library is also able to convert XML to JSON using `XML.toJSONObject(java.lang.String string)`

Check the [Javadoc](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)

Link to the [the github repository](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

*POM*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

*original post updated with new links*

Comment: thanks for it. how to write json object to add attrubute to element like
 <Private Provider="AB"/>

Comment: I guess the only way will be to deserialize the JSON to a (custom) Java Object. Then, using a framework like XMLBeans or XStream and with the help of annotations, specify which property goes as element and which goes as attribute

Comment: Alternatively, use the XML from the simple two lines above and apply an XSLT to it

Comment: can i have am example of it

Comment: Very convenient for simple one-to-one JSON to XML conversion.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get invalid xml out of valid json.

Comment: URL for javadoc is broken. Here is the [good one](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) and also the [github repo](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Comment: This works great most of the time. But one hast to be careful if they have keys in the JSON that might be valid in JSON, but not valid tag names in XML. For example keys starting with numbers work fine in JSON but fail with a standard XML parser.

Comment: I have a query related to this lib, please have a look once - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900503/json-xml-converter-having-array-in-json-string

Comment: This is not a valid answer as it generates invalid XML.

Comment: This library is good but has some problems .. 1) Order of tags is disturbed 2) Big numbers are converted to their exponential forms like 10017686.01 will become 1.001768601E7

Comment: This library not work in android studio 4.1.4.

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert any json to xml. It has check for special characters like numbers.

Answer (score 9):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method `U.jsonToXml(jsonstring)`. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/x1U)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String json = "{\"name\":\"JSON\",\"integer\":1,\"double\":2.0,\"boolean\":true,\"nested\":{\"id\":42},\"array\":[1,2,3]}";
        String xml = U.jsonToXml(json, U.JsonToXmlMode.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTES);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <name>JSON</name>
  <integer>1</integer>
  <double>2.0</double>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
  <nested>
    <id>42</id>
  </nested>
  <array>1</array>
  <array>2</array>
  <array>3</array>
</root>
```

Comment: thx for this. especially with mixed json object array structure its much easier than the top rated answer

Comment: @Valentyn - How to add `soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" ` while converting Json to XML ?

Comment: Thanks. This is best solution in 2020. Some other libraries not work.

Answer (score 7):

For **json to xml** use the following [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) example:

```
final String str = "{\"name\":\"JSON\",\"integer\":1,\"double\":2.0,\"boolean\":true,\"nested\":{\"id\":42},\"array\":[1,2,3]}";
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readValue(str, JsonNode.class);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
                xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
                xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
                xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_1_1, true);
ObjectWriter ow = xmlMapper.writer().withRootName("root");
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
ow.writeValue(w, node);
System.out.println(w.toString());
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <name>JSON</name>
  <integer>1</integer>
  <double>2.0</double>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
  <nested>
    <id>42</id>
  </nested>
  <array>1</array>
  <array>2</array>
  <array>3</array>
</root>
```

To convert it back (**xml to json**) take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468955/1485527 .

Comment: You'd better show how to override "ObjectNode".

Comment: @SimonLogic Good hint! 'Feature' added.

Comment: Is there a way to convert an array of objects in the JSON to a wrapped list in the XML? Say the JSON has `"objects": [{"value": 1}, {"value": 2}]`, is it possible to get `<objects><object><value>1</value></object><object><value>2</value></object></objects>`?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid dtd file for the xml then you can easily transform json to xml and xml to json using the eclipselink jar binary.

Refer this: http://www.cubicrace.com/2015/06/How-to-convert-XML-to-JSON-format.html

The article also has a sample project (including the supporting third party jars) as a zip file which can be downloaded for reference purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming with XSLT 3.0 is the only proper way to do it, as far as I can tell. It is guaranteed to produce valid XML, and a nice structure at that.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#json

Comment: This conversion now can also be done using our library: https://github.com/AtomGraph/JSON2XML

Answer (score -2):

If you want to replace any node value you can do like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
xml.replace("old value", "new value");
```