# Simple json to xml conversion

Tags: java, json, xml

can anyone share code to convert json to xml this is the json that comes through the request

```
{'sector':'Europe','organization':'Bazz Market Unit UK','companyCode':'UK1_2020','approvalManager':'03000069','managementLevel1':'X11','approvalLimit':'500000','access Category':'FTeam','currency':'USD','comments':'Need this access so I can do my job properly'}
```

I need json to xml as well as vice- versa .Can any one help me out, I'd prefer code with no jar imports required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to parse this with Java? Or you want just the results?

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to get this in Java without some imported lib. See here for an example of how to do it with a lib: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19978281/584599](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19978281/584599)

Comment: That json is not valid and can possible not be parsed because it has single instead of double quotes

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static methods U.jsonToXml(json) and U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java SE and can't use foreign JARs, *and* your JSON is always simple as the example you posted, you can parse it. Here's a short program that works *for your example* (but you will certainly have to adapt it if you have more complex JSON strings with more nesting levels and arrays):

```java
public class SimpleJsonToXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{'sector':'Europe','organization':'Bazz Market Unit UK','companyCode':'UK1_2020','approvalManager':'03000069','managementLevel1':'X11','approvalLimit':'500000','access Category':'FTeam','currency':'USD','comments':'Need this access, so I can do my job properly'}";
        String jsonObject = json.replaceAll("\\{(.*)\\}", "$1");
        String[] childElements = jsonObject.split("(,)(?=(?:[^\']|\'[^\']*\')*$)");

        System.out.println("<root>");
        for (String item : childElements) {
            System.out.println(makeTag(item));
        }
        System.out.println("</root>");
    }

    public static String makeTag(String jsonProperty) {
        String[] element = jsonProperty.split("\\:");
        String tagName = element[0].replaceAll("[' ]", "");
        String tagValue = element[1].replace("'", "");
        return "    <"+tagName+">"+tagValue+"</"+tagName+">";
    }
}
```

It will print:

```xml
<root>
    <sector>Europe</sector>
    <organization>Bazz Market Unit UK</organization>
    <companyCode>UK1_2020</companyCode>
    <approvalManager>03000069</approvalManager>
    <managementLevel1>X11</managementLevel1>
    <approvalLimit>500000</approvalLimit>
    <accessCategory>FTeam</accessCategory>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <comments>Need this access, so I can do my job properly</comments>
</root>
```

To convert XML back to JSON you can use the native Java XML tools and parsers (`org.w3c.dom` and `org.xml.sax`, for example) and won't need any external Jars.

If you are using at least Java EE 7, you can use the parsers in the [javax.json](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: how about these types of response jsons..  {
"statusResponse": 
{
"status": "failed",
"code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_MYBUY",
"prescriptiveDiagnostic": "User is not authorized for myBuy. Please request access first."
}
}
 or {
"statusResponse ": 
{
"status": "success"
},
"response":
{
<a successful response object>
}
}

Comment: It certainly is possible, but now we are moving toward a general solution (no longer "a simple json to xml conversion") and if we continue, we will end up reinventing a JSON Parser :) which is certainly a good programming exercise, but if you don't wish to reinvent the wheel, trying some existing packages or even incorporating the code (if you can't have foreign JARs) might be a better solution. Try this package: http://www.json.org/java/index.html It's very easy to use. Or use Java EE.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and works pretty well for me...

json to xml -

```
JSON jsonObject = JSONSerializer.toJSON(json); 
    XMLSerializer xmlSerialized = (new XMLSerializer());
    xmlSerialized.setTypeHintsEnabled(false);
    String xml = xmlSerialized.write( jsonObject );
```

and xml to json

```
org.json.JSONObject object;
    String json = null;
    try {
        object = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
         json = object.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Underscore-java library has static method U.jsonToXml(json).