# How can i convert a JSON structure to XML android

Tags: android, xml, json, android-asynctask, converters

Okay guys, i got an Invoice app that will send a list of Invoices stored in my Sqlite,

and i create a converter to took thes data from my db and send via HttpPost to my server, but the server only accept, ATOM/XML(rather) or XML ... how can i modify this class below to send as XML or ATOM/XML ??? any ideas ??

```
public class ItemNotaConverter {
public String toJSON(List<ItemNota> itemnotas) {
    try {
        JSONStringer jsonStringer = new JSONStringer();
        jsonStringer.object().key("list").array().object().key("itemnota").array();

        for (ItemNota itemnota : itemnotas) {
            jsonStringer.object().
            key("id_itemnota").value(itemnota.getId_itemnota()).
            key("conjunto").value(itemnota.getConjunto()).
            key("n_defeitos").value(itemnota.getNumeroDefeitos()).
            key("problema").value(itemnota.getProblema()).
            key("procedencia").value(itemnota.getProcedencia()).
            key("descri_detalhes").value(itemnota.getDescricao_problema()).
            endObject();
        }
        return jsonStringer.endArray().endObject().endArray().endObject().toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }}}
```

My WebClient Class to open the HttpRequest

```
public class WebClient {
    private final String url ;
        public WebClient(String url) {
            this.url = url; 
        }           
        public String post(String json) {
            try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));

            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            String jsonDeResposta = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            return jsonDeResposta;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }}}
```

And my AsyncTask to perform the "sending stuff"

```
public class EnviaNotasTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

    private final Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private final String enderecourl = "MyUrl";

    public EnviaNotasTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Aguarde...", "Envio de dados para Web", true, true);
    }
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Stara_DB dao = new Stara_DB(context);
        List<Nota> lista = dao.getListaNota();
        dao.close();

        String listaJson = new NotaConverter().toJSON(lista);
        String JsonResposta = new WebClient("MyUrl").post(listaJson);

        return JsonResposta;
    }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }}
```

Any helps wil be trully aprecciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json.org, the mothership of JSON, provides [a library that you can use](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/).

Here is how your JSON becomes XML:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

Source: [Converting JSON to XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java)

Comment: Underscore-java converts better. Plus MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method `U.jsonToXml(string)`. I am the maintainer of the project. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Ecb)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String json = "{\"Price\": {"
        + "    \"LineItems\": {"
        + "        \"LineItem\": {"
        + "            \"UnitOfMeasure\": \"EACH\", \"Quantity\": 2, \"ItemID\": \"ItemID\""
        + "        }"
        + "    },"
        + "    \"Currency\": \"USD\","
        + "    \"EnterpriseCode\": \"EnterpriseCode\""
        + "}}";
        System.out.println(U.jsonToXml(json)); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Price>
  <LineItems>
    <LineItem>
      <UnitOfMeasure>EACH</UnitOfMeasure>
      <Quantity number="true">2</Quantity>
      <ItemID>ItemID</ItemID>
    </LineItem>
  </LineItems>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
  <EnterpriseCode>EnterpriseCode</EnterpriseCode>
</Price>
```