# Is there a way to convert Json file to XML by using groovy script on soapUI?

Tags: xml, json, groovy, soapui

I need to convert Json file format into XML format, I've seen a lot of webpages that use this even in java I can see there are a lot of people who are capable of doing it but I can't find a way on groovy.

I have a file like this one:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I'd like to be able to convert directly to XML, since we need to use that to dynamically create the request for an operation.

Thank you in advance guys

Comment: Json doesn't map to XML without some planning on your part.  What are you going to do with the see also blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java) that can help you.

Based on the above link, here is the complete groovy script for the same.

```
import net.sf.json.JSON
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer

String str = '''{ "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } }'''
JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( str )
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer()
xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility( false )
String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json )
System.out.println(xml)
```

By the way, you need to download the [library](http://www.findjar.com/jar/net.sf.json-lib/jars/json-lib-0.9.jar.html) and add it to the *classpath*, in this case copy it under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory.

Comment: Good morning and thank you very much man! It worked like a charm, although the string has values such as "json_class="object"", example "<GlossDiv json_class="object">

I can manage that by replacing on the string , but do you know If there's a way to "format" that string into xml? because now If I save that to a file or whatever, I have like a big line of text

Answer (score 0):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static methods fromJson and toXml.

```
@Grab('com.github.javadev:underscore:1.32')
import com.github.underscore.U

def json = '''
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
'''

println U.toXml(U.fromJson(json))
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<glossary>
  <title>example glossary</title>
  <GlossDiv>
    <title>S</title>
    <GlossList>
      <GlossEntry>
        <ID>SGML</ID>
        <SortAs>SGML</SortAs>
        <GlossTerm>Standard Generalized Markup Language</GlossTerm>
        <Acronym>SGML</Acronym>
        <Abbrev>ISO 8879:1986</Abbrev>
        <GlossDef>
          <para>A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.</para>
          <GlossSeeAlso>
            <element>GML</element>
            <element>XML</element>
          </GlossSeeAlso>
        </GlossDef>
        <GlossSee>markup</GlossSee>
      </GlossEntry>
    </GlossList>
  </GlossDiv>
</glossary>
```