# How can i convert json to soap xml format by NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to consume a soap ws by using a json input. I am stuck in converting the json to xml. How can I create flow that convert from json to soap xml format by using NiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no processor that directly converts JSON to XML. One option would be to use ExecuteScript with a Groovy script that did the conversion. It looks like there are some examples out there of converting JSON to XML with Groovy:

[Is there a way to convert Json file to XML by using groovy script on soapUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459651/is-there-a-way-to-convert-json-file-to-xml-by-using-groovy-script-on-soapui)

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the JSON content in your flow file into the `ConvertRecord` processor. This processor takes in a reader and a writer. You could then configure a JSON Tree Reader to parse your JSON content, and the writer would need to be an `XMLRecordSetWriter`. Make sure you specify the element name in the configuration of the writer. Now, this is a vanilla writer which simply creates an XML equivalent of your JSON.

Input:

```
{
   "firstname": "John",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "age": "45",
}
```

Output:

```
<person>
   <firstname>John</firstname>
   <lastname>Doe</lastname>
   <age>45</age>
</person>
```

Now once you have the XML, you can pipe it through the `TransformerXML` processor. You should be able to set up the processor to use XSLT to create a SOAP XML payload as per your specification.

Answer (score -1):

I've a similar scenario, where Oracle registeres need to put in XML POST HTTP, one by one.

To solve I've created the follow flow, I putted some details (parameters/configurations) where I've setted:

**1) ExecuteSQLRecord**, details:

- SQL select query: select id, ip from server_table
- RecordWriter: JsonRecordSetWriter
- Max Rows Per Flow File: 1

**2) EvaluateJsonPath**, details:

- Destination: flowfile-attribute
- additional propertie 1: local.id
- additional value 1: $.[0].id
- additional propertie 2: local.ip
- additional value 2: $.[0].ip

**3) ReplaceText**, details:

- Search Value: (?s)(^.*$)
- Replacement Value (XML):

```
    <item>
        <id>${local.id}</id>
        <ip>${local.ip}</ip>
    </item>
```

- Replacement Strategy: Always Replace

**4) InvokeHTTP**, details:

- Run Schedule: 2 secs
- HTTP Method: POST Remote URL:
- https://restapi.xxx.com/apiREST/v2/items