# How to add wrapper while converting JSON array object into XML in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml

I want to convert JSON array into XML, but during conversion it generates invalid XML file:

```java
String str = "{ 'test' : [ {'a' : 'A'},{'b' : 'B'}]}"; 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

I used above code as suggested in [Converting JSON to XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java)

But if I tried to convert JSON object into XML it give invalid XML (error: `The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`) which is

```xml
<test><a>A</a></test><test><b>B</b></test>
```

Can anybody please tell me how to get valid XML from JSON array or how to wrap JSON array while converting into XML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML documents can have only one root element. Your XML result is actually:

```xml
<test>
    <a>A</a>
</test>
<test>
    <b>B</b>
</test>
```

where the second `test` element is clearly after the document root element closing tag. `XML.toString` has a nice overload accepting object and string to enclose the result XML:

```java
final String json = getPackageResourceString(Q43440480.class, "doc.json");
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
final String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject, "tests");
System.out.println(xml);
```

Now the output XML is well-formed:

```xml
<tests>
    <test>
        <a>A</a>
    </test>
    <test>
        <b>B</b>
    </test>
</tests>
```