# How can i return xml from a mongo connector in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, api

I am writing a RESTful web service where in I want to return a XML after doing a query in Mongo using a Mongo Connector.

I have searched alot and i didnt find any good tutorial online. Need Help XD

```
public class MongoConnector {
    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MongoConnector(){
        //TODO: Parameterizar connection string
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    }

    public String getData(String databaseName, String collectionName, String field, String value){
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);//"restaurantsDB"
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);//"restaurants"
        Bson filter = eq(field, value);//borough, bronx

        return StreamSupport.stream(collection.find(filter).limit(10).spliterator(), false)
                .map(Document::toJson)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")).toString();
    }

    public String aggregateDataByQueryString(String databaseName, String collectionName, String query){
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);//"restaurantsDB"
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);//"restaurants"
        BasicDBObject q = BasicDBObject.parse(query);
        //Mapear o resultado para um array em JSON
        return StreamSupport.stream(collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(q)).spliterator(), false)
                .map(Document::toJson)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i return xml from a mongo connector in Java?

Comment: Which method is supposed to return the XML?

Comment: getData returns Json i want to know if its possible to return xml. The code is a common mongo connector implemented in java

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978281/5645656)?

Comment: That cloud work. Thank you will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the MongoDB documentation, and poked around the internet a little, but I could not find anything defined within the API itself that can carry out your task. That being said, there are still a few options here that could work for you:

1. Because [`org.bson.Document`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html) implements [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), you can look at [How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa) as a potential solution.
2. Because you are mapping your document to a JSON string before returning it, you could try [Converting JSON to XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java/19978281#19978281) as another potential solution.

I am not too familliar with MongoDB, but I believe these solutions will work since a `Document` object is "a representation of a document as a Map," and because it can be cleanly [converted to a JSON](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--) string.