# How to convert arrays JSON to XML?

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

I have json:

```
{
"Owner": {
    "A": [{
      "LastName": "d1",
      "FirstName": "d1",
      "MiddleName": "d1"
    },
      {
        "LastName": "d2",
        "FirstName": "d2",
        "MiddleName": "d2"
      }
    ],
    "B": [{
      "FullName": "d3"
    },
      {
        "FullName": "d4"
      }
    ],
    "C": [{
      "LastName": "d5",
      "FirstName": "d5",
    },
      {
        "LastName": "d6",
        "FirstName": "d6",
      }
    ]
  }
```

I try to convert json to XML, For it i was use xjc.
XJC was generate this code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"A","B","C"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Owner")
public static class Owner {
    @XmlElement(name = "A")
    protected List<A> a;
    @XmlElement(name = "B")
    protected List<B> b;
    @XmlElement(name = "C")
    protected List<C> c;
```

I try to marshalling to XML, but I get  Exception

> IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Comment: have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java