# How to parse or read JSON into an XML document for BaseX?

Tags: java, json, xml, basex

This [one-liner](https://github.com/THUFIR/helloPSTwitterAPI) in `powershell` achieves the purpose of converting `JSON` from `Twitter` to `XML`, albeit probably formatted differently:

```
$tweets = Get-Content 'tweets.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | Export-Clixml "./tweets.xml"
```

Also, certainly it's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19977979/262852) enough to create an `XML` document from a `JSON` file using `org.json` below:

```
package basex;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.MainOptions;
import org.basex.io.IOFile;

public class JsonToXmlTransformer {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JsonToXmlTransformer.class.getName());

    public JsonToXmlTransformer() {
    }

    private void baseXparseJsonFile(String fileName) throws IOException   {
        org.basex.build.json.JsonParser jsonParser = new org.basex.build.json.JsonParser(new IOFile(fileName), new MainOptions());
        //where is the xml?
    }

    public void transform(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(content);
        log.info(org.json.XML.toString(json));
    }
}
```

but how can I [create](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60016071/262852) an `XML` document [using](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.1#fn:json-to-xml) the `BaseX` API?  While it [sounds](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2015-September/009607.html) doable, how, exactly, is it accomplished?

Comment: How about using something from the [BaseX JSON_MODULE](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module).

Comment: ... like as shown at http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Twitter

Comment: must be blind, @rickhg12hs, but I'm not seeing how to use that module from Java?  Perhaps I'm not understanding your meaning.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize you wanted to do this from Java.  I'm not familiar with using BaseX from Java, but I have found the developers to be shockingly responsive and helpful.  Really, they respond to just about everyone and incrementally improve BaseX continuously.  If you don't receive a good response here, seriously consider posting your issue to the [BaseX talk maillist](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk).