# where is toXML in JsonParser, and why is the method not available?

Tags: java, json, xml, gradle, basex

How do I invoke the [following](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/build/json/JsonParser.java) method `JsonParser`:

```
  /**
   * Converts a JSON document to XML.
   * @param io input
   * @param options parser options
   * @return parser
   * @throws IOException I/O exception
   */
  private static IOContent toXML(final IO io, final JsonParserOptions options) throws IOException {
    final JsonConverter conv = JsonConverter.get(options);
    final IOContent xml = new IOContent(conv.convert(io).serialize().finish());
    xml.name(io.name());
    return xml;
  }
```

yet I'm certainly not seeing this method from the IDE:

[image: screenshot]

The [method is in](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/build/json/JsonParser.html) the JavaDocs:

```
Method Detail

    toXML

    public static IOContent toXML(IO io,
                  JsonParserOptions options)
                           throws java.io.IOException

    Converts a JSON document to XML.

    Parameters:
        io - input
        options - parser options
    Returns:
        parser
    Throws:
        java.io.IOException - I/O exception
```

The build file is using:

`compile group: 'org.basex', name: 'basex', version: '9.2.4'`

which is the most recent version I see on the repository:

```
maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/" }
```

I went so far as to assemble the project and extracted the `.class` file from the `JAR` from the resulting `BaseX` but didn't go futher to find if this method is there or not.

Perhaps I'm just not [invoking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60022419/262852) the method properly?

Answer (score 0):

whoops:

```
package basex;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.build.json.JsonParser;
import org.basex.build.xml.SAXWrapper;
import org.basex.core.MainOptions;
import org.basex.io.IOFile;

public class JsonToXmlTransformer {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JsonToXmlTransformer.class.getName());

    public JsonToXmlTransformer() {
    }

    private void baseXparseJsonFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        org.basex.build.json.JsonParser jsonParser = new org.basex.build.json.JsonParser(new IOFile(fileName), new MainOptions());

        SAXWrapper foo = org.basex.build.json.JsonParser.xmlParser(new IOFile(fileName));
        foo.parse();
        String bar = foo.toString();
        log.info(bar);
    }

    public void transform(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(content);
        log.info(org.json.XML.toString(json));
    }
}
```

had the wrong package...