# How to convert JSON to a specified XML format

Tags: java, json, xml

I am new to JAVA and I faced the following problem.

I have a JSON file and the target is to convert to XML. Conversion should be in the following format.

```xml
<a attribute1 = "" attribute2 = "" />
```

but the conversion happened as follows

```xml
<a><attribute1>value</attribute1><attribute2>value<attribute2></a>
```

How exactly can i convert maintaining the desired XML format?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 0):

```
##Use json.jar for creating JSON to xml 
Steps:
1 .Add below mentioned artifacts to pom


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20200518</version>
 </dependency>

2.Use below code template for converting JOSN to xml       
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_data);
        String xml_data = XML.toString(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

No standard library for JSON-to-XML or XML-to-JSON is ever going to give you exactly the format you want. Let the library create the XML it creates, and then transform it using an XSLT stylesheet. Alternatively do a custom conversion all the way from JSON to XML using XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This json

```json
{
   "a": {
      "-attribute1": "",
      "-attribute2": "",
      "-self-closing": "true"
   },
   "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

may be converted to this xml

```xml
<a attribute1="" attribute2=""/>
```

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library