# Android:Convert Json object to Strings.xml

Tags: android, json, xml, string, kotlin

[image: JsonToStrings]

I have thousand of strings in Json and I wanted to convert into xml(strings.xml) .Is there any short way to do that ? plugins ? or I have to do it one by one?

Comment: Do you want to do in within your program? Or do you just convert a json file to xml for each entries?

Comment: just want to convert which give me above results and same i could paste it in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the json to xml in your app, you can use any existing library. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978281/603742) refers to one such.

If you just want to simply convert a json contents to xml, you can use any online converter. [This one](https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm) came first in my google search result. (But I would check the site's reliability before uploading any sensitive data)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not giving me what I'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire JSON into a `String` object, and get the XML representation with `Regex` and `.replace()` method Of a String

Here is a smaple

```
val json = """{
                "text_download_complete":"your file is downloaded"
            }"""

val xml = json.replace("\\{\\s*".toRegex(), "<string name=")
    .replace(":\\s*\"".toRegex(), ">")
    .replace("\"\\s*\\}".toRegex(), "</string>")

Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCreate: XML:\n$xml")
```

You can also read the JSON file instead of coping the entire file into a String...

I believe that won't be the optimum solution, but I think it would be a one shot task, and just wanted to be simple rather than looking at performance.