# How can I convert the complete Json String into an XML in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

First i hope the topic is not old, but i didn't find something. So either you can write me a solution hint or where i find the topic. Thanks.
And here is my problem i get a json response string back. The String looks like this:

```
{
    "total": 3,
    "hasMore": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskId": "1",
            "processName": "request new requests",
           
        },
        {
            "taskId": "2",
            "processName": "request new requests",
           
        },
        {
            "taskId": "3",
            "processName": "request new requests",
           
        }
    ],
    "totalSize": 6,
    "nextIndex": 5,
    "userTypeInTask": false
}
```

My goal is to convert this string to XML as follows:

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <taskId>1</taskId>
        <processName>request new requests</processName>
    </task>
    <task>
        <taskId>2</taskId>
        <processName>request new requests</processName>
    </task>
    <task>
        <taskId>2</taskId>
        <processName>request new requests</processName>
    </task>
    <totalSize>6</totalSize>
    <total>3</total>
    <hasMore>true</hasMore>
    <nextIndex>5</nextIndex>
    <userTypeInTask>false</userTypeInTask>
</tasks>
```

I managed to get the array but then I lose the other information.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class jsontest {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jsonstring = "{\"total\": 3,\"hasMore\": true,\"tasks\":[{\"taskId\":\"1\",\"processName\": \"request new requests\"},{\"taskId\":\"2\",\"processName\": \"request new requests\"},{\"taskId\":\"2\",\"processName\": \"request new requests\"}],\"totalSize\": 6,\"nextIndex\": 5,\"userTypeInTask\": false}";
        String parent = "tasks";
        String child = "task";

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
        System.out.println("json: " + json);

        if (json.has(parent)) {

            JSONObject dataObject = json.optJSONObject(parent);

            if (dataObject != null) {

                System.out.println("dataObject 1: " + dataObject);

            } else {

                System.out.println("dataObject 2: " + dataObject);
                JSONArray array = dataObject.getJSONArray(parent);
                System.out.println("array: " + array);

                String xml = "<" + parent + ">" + org.json.XML.toString(array, child) + "</" + parent + ">";
                System.out.println("xml: " + xml);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for my problem?

Comment: I would look at Jackson XML Mapper [XML Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization), The way I would go about it use Jackson to convert the Json to a POJO and then use the XML mapper to convert to XML

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I was looking for but it can work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978281/9474700
first import library in your gradle

> implementation 'org.json:json:20211205'

then do as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

**Second option**

Use from underscore-java

import library

```
implementation 'com.github.javadev:underscore:1.74'
```

then

```
String xml = U.jsonToXml(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had already worked with the Json.Org and also with the underscore, both of which were not satisfactory for what I was looking for. I've now decided on the ObjectMapper and XmlMapper.